# do/while loop does not work

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

can someone help me to do this loop. when someone input Y when the loop ask "do you have another name". it will keep asking the same question until the user input N.

```
char ans;

do {
cout<<"Do you have another name (Y/N)?\n";


while(ask!="y"!! ans!!="n") {
      cout<<"you must enter 'Y' or an 'N'.\n";  
      cin >> ans; 
}

if(ans=='y')
    enter other name();
elseif  end;
```

Comment: Next time, put in enough effort to at least make it compile, then put a comment on the line you think needs to change.  Right now you've got horrible syntax errors.

Answer (score 5):

It is simple & pretty straightforward:

```
string answer;
do {
    enter_other_name();
    cout << "Do you have another name (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
} while(answer!="n");
```

It will bug user, until he enters **n**. If you want to keep bugging while he is pressing **y**, then change last line to `} while(answer=="y");`

Answer (score 1):

That code just doesn't make sense. You have an unterminated do loop, and a while loop, you are comparing a char with a char *, !!= isn't a valid operator...

Please, post some code that compiles. By the time you've got it to compile, you might have worked out what the issue is.

As far as posting examples is concerned, copy and paste is your friend.